# Optimise PNG images

Tags: image, ce-1.4.1.1

How can I optimize PNG images in Magento?
The is already compression for jpg files, but no compression for png files in `/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike JPEG format PNG is not supporting compression via downsampling. You can try to reduce size of your PNG files by exporting the same file as 8-bit PNG. Also there are some 3rd party services for compressing PNGs like [TinyPNG](http://tinypng.org/) or [PunyPNG](http://www.punypng.com/).

Eventually none of them is supported neither by Magento nor by GD2 lib. So you either have to do it manually before uploading images to Magento or to write your own integration.

Comment: In the meantime, there are [M1](https://github.com/tinify/magento1-plugin) and [M2](https://github.com/tinify/magento2-plugin) extensions of tinfy (TinyPNG / TinyJPG).

Comment: And lots of clouds. ☁️☁️☁️ 